# error on Button.setOnClickListener(listener);

Tags: android

```
private int ServiceLeft;
private int ServiceRight;
private int Services;

final TextView countTextViewPlusL = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextViewCountL);
final Button ServiceButtonLeft = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonServiceLeft);
final TextView countTextViewPlusR = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextViewCountR);
final Button ServiceButtonRight = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonServiceRight);

ServiceButtonLeft.setOnClickListener(listener);
ServiceButtonRight.setOnClickListener(listener);

View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()) {
            case R.id.ButtonServiceRight:
                ServiceRight++;
                break;
            case R.id.ButtonServiceLeft:
                ServiceLeft++;
                break;
        }

        if(Services % 2 == 0) {
            getDrawable(R.drawable.test);
        }
    }
};
```

i get an error on these 2 lines: on the word "listener"

```
ServiceButtonLeft.setOnClickListener(listener);
ServiceButtonRight.setOnClickListener(listener);
```

Comment: @CapDroid i deleted `ServiceButtonLeft.setOnClickListener(listener);
ServiceButtonRight.setOnClickListener(listener);` but now i get an error on **getDrawable** `getDrawable(R.drawable.test);` it says `The method getDrawable(int) is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener(){}`. how to solve this

Answer (score 0):

```
 public class MyActivity extends Activity implements OnclickListener{
    private int ServiceLeft;
    private int ServiceRight;
    private int Services;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance){
super(savedInstance);
setContent(R.layout.main);
final TextView countTextViewPlusL = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextViewCountL);
final Button ServiceButtonLeft = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonServiceLeft);
final TextView countTextViewPlusR = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextViewCountR);
final Button ServiceButtonRight = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonServiceRight);

//set Listeners for your buttons
ServiceButtonLeft.setOnClickListener(this);
ServiceButtonRight.setOnClickListener(this);
 }
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
switch(v.getId()) {
    case R.id.ButtonServiceRight:
        ServiceRight++;
        break;
    case R.id.ButtonServiceLeft:
        ServiceLeft++;
        break;
}

if(Services % 2 == 0) {
    getDrawable(R.drawable.test);
}
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

You create 'listener' after you try and use it. Try it this way.

```
View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()) {
        case R.id.ButtonServiceRight:
            ServiceRight++;
            break;
        case R.id.ButtonServiceLeft:
            ServiceLeft++;
            break;
    }

    if(Services % 2 == 0) {
        getDrawable(R.drawable.test);
    }
}
};

ServiceButtonLeft.setOnClickListener(listener);
ServiceButtonRight.setOnClickListener(listener);
```

Comment: i get the same errors:

`- Syntax error on token "listener", VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token`

`- Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)`

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to use (or even refer to) a variable before it's been created. You need to move the two lines using "listener"

```
ServiceButtonLeft.setOnClickListener(listener);
ServiceButtonRight.setOnClickListener(listener);
```

to after you've created it, i.e. last row in the code snippet you've provided above. Then it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()) {
        case R.id.ButtonServiceRight:
            ServiceRight++;
            break;
        case R.id.ButtonServiceLeft:
            ServiceLeft++;
            break;
    }

    if(Services % 2 == 0) {
        getDrawable(R.drawable.test);
    }
}
};
```

**Edited Part:**
Try to replace your asked code with the following one:

```
private int ServiceLeft;
private int ServiceRight;
private int Services;

final TextView countTextViewPlusL = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextViewCountL);
final Button ServiceButtonLeft = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonServiceLeft);
final TextView countTextViewPlusR = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextViewCountR);
final Button ServiceButtonRight = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonServiceRight);

OnClickListener listener;     //This line is the only change to your code.
ServiceButtonLeft.setOnClickListener(listener);
ServiceButtonRight.setOnClickListener(listener);

View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()) {
            case R.id.ButtonServiceRight:
                ServiceRight++;
                break;
            case R.id.ButtonServiceLeft:
                ServiceLeft++;
                break;
        }

        if(Services % 2 == 0) {
            getDrawable(R.drawable.test);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: if i remove the 2 lines i get an error on getDrawable

`The method getDrawable(int) is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener(){}`

Comment: Try to replace the `getDrawable(R.drawable.test);` with `<YourActivityClassName>.this.getDrawable(R.drawable.test);`

Comment: now i get the error: `The method getDrawable(int) is undefined for the type counter`

"counter" is my ActivityClassName

Comment: The method `getDrawable()` is defined in the Resources class. So you need to add `.getResources()` after the context. From within a new anonymous listener class this would be `<YourActivityClassName>.this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.test);`